# Blazor Server Side Authorization

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, blazor-server-side

I have been trying to Implement Authorization in my Server Side Blazor application, currently it seems to be working but the Authorization is limited to the `.razor` pages and components.
 Try as I might I cant seem to get the [Authorize] `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` attributes to work in my underlying services.

Currently the only means of enforcing this is to read the claims directly from the `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` witch can be injected into the underlying services.
 I can also call the RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider.

I have the following setup correctly Registered in my Startup.cs`

- `RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<TUser>`
- `app.UseAuthentication();`
- `app.UseAuthorization();`

along with a `CascadingAuthenticationState` and `AuthorizeRouteView` in the App.razor

These are functioning and do indeed authorize and restricts access were needed.
 My biggest issue is that I originally planned on driving the Navigation with the "Front End" Authorization but restrict actions in the services themselves.

As a quick side note, I spun up a new Template with Individual User Account Authentication, it also seems to ignore any [Authorize] tags placed in the WeatherForecastService.cs

```
 [Authorize]
 public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
 {
    ** Boiler Plate Code **
 }
```

Any suggestions in overcoming this issue, I also suspect I may be barking up the wrong tree as this is all server side and thus there is no real need to Authorize the underlying services.

Comment: If you've setup the default authorization policy like JWT, then the Authorize attribute should work as intended.

Comment: This could be a way of getting the result I intended, thank you. I will look into it. But would this not then require me to create api endpoints and thus ignore blazor's service injection capabilities on the .razor pages?  

I guess I will need to get a better understanding of blazor's Architecture this solution seems counter intuitive to my understanding of blazor.

Comment: Take a look at [Secure ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It covers different setup such as standalone with authentication library, hosted with identity server, etc. see if your use-case is covered.

Comment: This makes sense for WebAssembly as you would need to have some form of api backing the application thus Tokens make for great authentication. 

_In Blazor WebAssembly apps, authorization checks can be bypassed because all client-side code can be modified by users. The same is true for all client-side app technologies, including JavaScript SPA frameworks or native apps for any operating system._

 Does this mean The reverse is true for Blazor Server Side?

Comment: Going by the Blazor Server side architecture, it seems to me that Authorization can be left at the .razor views and components, as everything is executed server side, thus theres no real need for [Authorize] attributes on the underlying services. 

This would be different in the case of Blazor WebAssembly, as the Backing API's will need to be secured.

Comment: Didn't know what crossed my mind that I sent WebAssembly link. For Blazor Server-Side, authentication and authorization is the same as a .NET Core Web App. I don't know how to word this out but if you apply authorize in an `IActionResult` instead it should work. You can authorize pages on the razor pages instead.

Comment: No worries, I expect it would confuse many of us, as even the Blazor WebAssembly apps, need "Server Side" Authorization/Authentication